# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: Task never defined: app/scss/**/*.scss

Tags: javascript, gulp4

Появилась проблема с запуском таска, видимо проблема в непонимании, gulp4, но не понимаю с чем связана ошибка.
**gulpfile.js**

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var scss = require("gulp-sass");
var browserSync = require("browser-sync");

gulp.task('compile', function(){
    gulp.parallel("app/scss/**/*.scss")
        .pipe(scss())
        .pipe(gulp.parallel('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream);

        done();
});
gulp.task("watch", function(done) {

    browserSync.init({
        server:'app/'
    })

    gulp.watch("app/sccs/**/*.scss", gulp.series('scss'));
    gulp.watch('app/*.html').on('change',()=>{
        browserSync.reload();
        done();
    });
    done();
})

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('compile', 'watch'));
```

**Код ошибки в консоли:**

```
[23:04:08] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Project_1\gulpfile.js
[23:04:08] Starting 'default'...
[23:04:08] Starting 'compile'...
[23:04:08] 'compile' errored after 6.63 ms
[23:04:08] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: app/scss/**/*.scss
    at getFunction (C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\Project_1\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\normalizeArgs.js:15:5)
    at map (C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\Project_1\node_modules\arr-map\index.js:20:14)
    at normalizeArgs (C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\Project_1\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\normalizeArgs.js:22:10)
    at Gulp.parallel (C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\Project_1\node_modules\undertaker\lib\parallel.js:13:14)
    at C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\Project_1\gulpfile.js:6:10
    at taskWrapper (C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\Project_1\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:395:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:408:12)
    at asyncRunner (C:\Users\Gleb\Desktop\Project_1\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[23:04:08] 'default' errored after 66 ms
```

**Доп.инфа.:**

```
{
  "name": "project_1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Причина этой ошибки в том, что вы используйте `gulp.parallel()` вместо `gulp.src()` и `gulp.dest()`

`gulp.parallel()` предназначен для того, чтобы параллельно запустить несколько задач

`gulp.src()` читает файлы

А `gulp.dest()` записывает в файлы

Кроме того, `done()` в задаче watch не нужны, а `browserSync.stream` в `.pipe()` нужно вызвать (то есть `.pipe(browserSync.stream())`), как сказано в [документации BrowserSync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-sass-css)

В итоге, если исправить допущенные ошибки, получается такой gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var scss = require("gulp-sass");
var browserSync = require("browser-sync");

gulp.task('compile', function(){
    return gulp.src("app/scss/**/*.scss")
        .pipe(scss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task("watch", function(done) {
    browserSync.init({
        server:'app/'
    })

    gulp.watch("app/scss/**/*.scss", gulp.series('compile'));
    gulp.watch('app/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('compile', 'watch'));
```